# React - inserting variable into Route path

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have an app that I am creating and am wondering how you would insert variables into the `<Route path={insert variable here} component={myProfile}>`  I am trying to create a myProfile page and I am trying to get it so when they click onto the link, it redirects them to `http://mywebsite.com/userId` but when I try to create a `Route` with a variable in the `path` argument, it does not return the component I am trying to render when on that path.

**routes.js**

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor"
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "../ui/authentication/Login";
import Signup from "../ui/authentication/Signup";
import Home from "../ui/Home";
import { SubjectRoutes } from "../ui/subjectRoutes/subjectRoutes";
import AddNote from "../ui/AddNote";
import myProfile from "../ui/myProfile";
import NotFound from "../ui/NotFound";

export default class Routes extends React.Component{
  renderSubjectRoutes(subjects){
    return subjects.map((subject) => {
      return <Route key={subject.name} path={subject.path} component={subject.component}/>
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Login path="/login" />
            <Signup path="/signup" />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
            {this.renderSubjectRoutes(SubjectRoutes)}
            <AddNote path="/addNote"/>
            <myProfile path={Meteor.userId()} /> //<-- Here
            <NotFound />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Menu.js**

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor"
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { SubjectRoutes } from "./subjectRoutes/subjectRoutes";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";

class Menu extends React.Component{
  renderMenu(items){
    return items.map((item) => {
      return <p key={item.name}><Link to={item.path}>{item.name}</Link></p>
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        {this.renderMenu(SubjectRoutes)}
        <p><Link to="/addNote">Add a Note</Link></p>
        <p><Link to={Meteor.userId()}>My Profile</Link></p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(Menu)
```

Answer (score 11):

You are creating way more work for yourself, and this is the wrong way to add variables to route. What you're looking to do is add `params` to your route. In your case, you would want it to look something like this.

```
<Route path="/user/:userId" />
```

The `:` is what denotes that it is a parameter, ready to render a path based on the `userId`. So if you went to route `/user/123` - it would be able to render user 123's data.

Here's some documentation to help you out.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: So would I replace userId with Meteor.userId()??? Sorry, I am quite new to Meteor and react